# Add placeholder text to input/textarea fields on Cognito form

Tags: cognito-forms

How I can add placeholder in my input/textarea fields?

Answer (score 1):

[Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) does not currently allow you to specify a HTML placeholder for text fields. However, you can specify a default value that will appear as a prompt for users that they can later replace.

The following shows how you would specify a default value for a text field.

[image: default value]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That's what I am doing right now but I don't think is a best option because in that case required will not work properly. So I think forms should have placeholder.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a required field and want to utilize Jamie's recommendation, you could use the "Show Custom Error" feature to show a custom error message and prevent the form from being submitted. Below is an example:

[image]

You would then get an error when you try to submit the form and the text was not modified from "Placeholder text.".

[image]